# unable to use makefile with make command

Tags: makefile, cmake, mingw-w64, vmime

when I cd to the path contains the makefile and run make command(from the MINGW64.exe) I get this error:

```
$ make
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -HC:\vmime-master -BC:\vmime-master\build --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) ▒▒௮▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ (Microsoft Corporation), 2016. ▒▒ ▒ࠢ▒ ▒▒▒饭▒.

C:\vmime-master\build>
```

Really have no clue how to resolve this. The make file was generated by mingw makefiles from cmake.It looks like it switched somehow to the windows command shell(cmd).I'm using the msys2+mingw64 tools. Any idea or advice is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: however, if I do the same, but from cmd: cd <path with makefile> , and run mingw32-make then it's start the building of the library.

Comment: I don't see an error. Is there maybe nothing to build?

Comment: from windows cmd make works, however from mingw64 shell nope. And gcc from command line differ from the one installed with mingw64.